# FindRoot & Non-negativity constraints

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, programming

I employ FindRoot to solve a large optimization problem. I formulate the optimization problem in terms of first-order conditions (in that specific problem, methods based on the objective function do not work).

My specific question is the following. How can I make FindRoot obey my non-negativity constraints?

More specifically, I added complementary slackness conditions to the objective function, plus I added min- (= zero) and max bounds on the choice variables.

FindRoot finds a Root that, in spite of my “constraints”   yields negative values of the choice variables (that were supposed to be non-negative), plus Lagrange multipliers at magnitude of 10^{-53}, so that, I think, the complementary slackness conditions are satisfied numerically, to some degree.

I would appreciate any hints you might have. How can I avoid, FindRoot produce strictly negative numbers in spite of complementary slackness conditions & a lower bound of zero for the choice variables?

Minimum code with negative l(i) for Types 2 and 3 - though l(i) should be zero or positive

```
Distribution

Clear["Global`*"]; 
pdf = 1/((Sqrt[2*Pi]*wi*sig)*E^((Log[wi] - Log[wmedian])^2/(2*sig^2))); 
cdf = 1/2 + (1/2)*Erf[(Log[wi] - Log[wmedian])/(Sqrt[2]*sig)]; 
sig = Sqrt[2*Log[wmean/wmedian]]; 
wmean0 = 1; 
wmedian0 = 0.66; 
sig0 = sig /. {wmedian -> wmedian0, wmean -> wmean0}; 
Gini0 = Erf[sig0/2]; 
population = 10000; 
wmean = wmean0; 
wmedian = wmedian0; 
w[0] = 0; 
maxW = 5; 
maxType = 100; 
Do[w[i] = ((maxW + 0)/maxType)*i, {i, 1, maxType}]; 
Do[n[i] = ((cdf /. wi -> w[i]) - (cdf /. wi -> w[i - 1]))*population, 
   {i, 1, maxType}]; 

Model

Do[u[i] = Log[c[i]] + \[Eta]*Log[z[i]], {i, 1, maxType, 1}]; 
Do[z[i] = 1 - l[i], {i, 1, maxType, 1}]; 

W := Sum[n[i]*u[i], {i, 1, maxType, 1}]; 

Do[uhat[i] = Log[c[i - 1]] + \[Eta]*Log[1 - (w[i - 1]/w[i])*l[i - 1]], 
   {i, 2, maxType, 1}]; 
Do[selfsel[i] = u[i] - uhat[i], {i, 2, maxType, 1}]; 

aggregateC = Sum[n[i]*c[i], {i, 1, maxType, 1}]; 
aggregateY = Sum[n[i]*w[i]*l[i], {i, 1, maxType, 1}]; 
resource := aggregateY - aggregateC; 

LEP = W + \[Gamma]*resource + Sum[\[Lambda][i]*selfsel[i], {i, 2, maxType}] + 
    Sum[\[Lambda]l[i]*l[i], {i, 1, maxType}]; Do[eqc[i] = D[LEP, c[i]] == 0, 
   {i, 1, maxType}]; Do[eql[i] = D[LEP, l[i]] == 0, {i, 1, maxType}]; 
eq\[Gamma] = D[LEP, \[Gamma]] == 0; 
Do[eq\[Lambda][i] = D[LEP, \[Lambda][i]] == 0, {i, 2, maxType}]; 
Do[eq\[Lambda]l[i] = D[LEP, \[Lambda]l[i]]*\[Lambda]l[i] == 0, {i, 1, maxType}]; 

sys := Flatten[{Table[{eqc[i], eql[i], eq\[Lambda]l[i]}, {i, 1, maxType}], 
     Table[eq\[Lambda][i], {i, 2, maxType}], eq\[Gamma]}]; 

Baseline simulation (FindRoot)

par = {\[Eta] -> 0.8}; 
solCGuesspoint = Table[{c[i], 0.15 + 0.03*i}, {i, 1, maxType}]; 
solLGuesspoint = Table[{l[i], 0.007*i}, {i, 1, maxType}]; 
sol\[Gamma]Guesspoint = {{\[Gamma], 2.2}}; 
sol\[Lambda]Guesspoint = Table[{\[Lambda][i], 0.3}, {i, 2, maxType}]; 
sol\[Lambda]lGuesspoint = Table[{\[Lambda]l[i], 0.5}, {i, 1, maxType}]; 
solGuesspoint = Flatten[{solCGuesspoint, solLGuesspoint, sol\[Gamma]Guesspoint, 
     sol\[Lambda]Guesspoint, sol\[Lambda]lGuesspoint}, 1]; 

sol = FindRoot[sys //. par, solGuesspoint]; 

Print[TableForm[Table[{"Type", i, Round[(c[i] /. sol)*1000]/1000., 
       Round[(l[i] /. sol)*1000]/1000.} /. sol /. par, {i, 1, maxType}]]]
```

One might ask my question also differently. Suppose one is interested to find a root at which a choice variable, say l[i] as in the code, must be non-negative. Whenever, though, a minimum value (zero) is specified in FindRoot, Mathematica stops evaluation, indicating search for a root is at the “edge of the search region {0.,1.} in coordinate … and the computed search direction points outside the region.” How can one solve this problem?

Comment: Please give a minimal example in code, and data to go with it. It may be otherwise difficult to answer this in general.

Comment: Thank you, @MarcoB. I will try. The main challenge is that this only occurs in my "big" model. And that takes probably 15 minutes to evaluate. If I reduce the number of "types",  the model produces solutions more quickly. But then, also corner solutions vanish. As a compromise, I will post the model such that I have at least one corner solution (which, according to programming should produce a value equal to zero for the respective choice variable, but FindRoot is going to produce a negative value for that variable.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the issue but In software that doesn't allow explicit non-negativity constraints on parameters one can replace the parameter (call it $\alpha$) with $e^{log\alpha}$.  The variable $log\alpha$ will then always produce a non-negative value for $\alpha$.

Comment: @MarcoB I wrote a minimum code, for which l[2] and l[3] are negative, while they should be zero. Adding the complementary slackness condition (... + lambda[i]*l[i] ... in the Lagrange function) seems not to be the way it works. Also, setting lower and upper bounds on l[i], with zero = lower bound, is not effective, as FindRoot stops evaluating, once l[i] becomes negative during the calculation.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your note. I tried this, but Mathematica automatically converts Exp[Log[a]] to a. So, this was not making a difference.

Comment: I was too subtle:  use `loga` as the name of the variable rather than `Log[a]`.  Otherwise, indeed `Exp[Log[a]]` will get converted to `a`.

Comment: @JimB I see, very clever. My problem, though, is that a number of the a-variables are zero in the optimum. That is, "loga" is not defined in that case, I think.

Comment: Then if you find that `loga` is estimated to be -1,000 and `Exp[-1000]` is not close enough to zero for you, then you set the original parameter to zero and go from there.